# Declaration of OM\Db::query(string $statement) must be compatible with PDO::query

Tags: php, php-8

I just installed PHP 8 and I have this error appears? How do I fix it?

> Fatal error: Declaration of OM\Db::query(string $statement) must be compatible with PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs) in /home/www/includes/OM/Db.php on line 131

My OM/Db.php

```
public function query(string $statement) =====> line 131
{
  $statement = $this->autoPrefixTables($statement);

  $args = func_get_args();

  if (count($args) > 1) {
    $DbStatement = call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::query'), $args);
  } else {
    $DbStatement = parent::query($statement);
  }

  if ($DbStatement !== false) {
    $DbStatement->setQueryCall('query');
    $DbStatement->setPDO($this);
  }

  return $DbStatement;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

1. Remove **`"doctrine/dbal": "^2.10"`** from **`composer.json`**
2. Then (and finally) run **`composer update`**

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the error message a bit, the signature of the `query` function in your class must be compatible with the parent method in the PDO class.

Where you have this:

```
public function query(string $statement)
```

, the parent class has this:

```
public function query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs)
```

For a child class to be commpatible, PHP requires that **all** arguments (including optional ones) are defined in the function signature when a method is overridden*

Thankfully, your *implementation* of the function is already compatible, as you always pass all the arguments to the parent. This means the solution is nice and simple: just change line 131 in your class to

```
public function query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, ...$fetchModeArgs)
```

and you should be good to go.

*  Earlier versions of PHP raised either warnings or strict standards notices about this, but it was changed to a fatal error in PHP 8. See https://3v4l.org/uJYG1

Comment: Hello, I tried this but it do not work.
 public function query ( string $statement , int $fetch_style = null, ?string $classname , ?array $ctorargs )

Comment: Right - that's still different from the parent method signature, so you'll get the same error. It needs to be compatible with the parent, removing arguments or adding extra ones isn't allowed. If you want a method with other arguments, you'll need to give it a different name.

Comment: What is exactly the parent function ? this is not clear - public function query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, ...$fetchModeArgs) - Tk

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error, for me it helped to replace

```
public function query(string $statement)
```

with

```
public function runQuery(string $statement)
```

I got the solution in a hint [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3185918):

> Due to PHP 8.0's signature checks on LSP, DatabaseConnection::query method was renamed to DatabaseConnection::runQuery. All database drivers will now need to rename to this method for PHP 8.0 compatibility.